# Why is this -1=1 proof incorrect?

Tags: radicals, fake-proofs

We  have

1=1
1²=1²

Since, (-1)²=1=1², we have
1²=(-1)²

So, taking square root on both sides gives
1=-1.

Obviously, this is wrong, but where is the mistake?

Is it because taking the square root on both sides of   1²=(-1)²  should give
+or-1=+or-1, and not 1=-1?

If so, then why is it okay to write::  x²=4  <=>  x=+or-2?

Shouldn't it then be:: x²=4  <=>  +or-x=+or-2?

Thanks.

Comment: Taking square root on both side you have $|1|=|-1|$.

Comment: The square function is not injective. As such, even if $a^2 = b^2$, that does not mean that $a = b$. Of course, $a$ and $b$ are definitely related, but care needs to be taken in such a step, whereas the fake proof doesn't consider it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble is that the squaring function cannot be inverted "cleanly", because if we have $x^2 = 4$, then there are two possibilities for what $x$ could be (namely $2$ and $-2$). Thus if we have $x^2 = a^2$, then we can remove the two squares, but we must account for the possibility of negative solutions by manually saying $x = \pm a$.

Looking at your particular case: $(1)^2 = (-1)^2$ we can apply the same logic to conclude
$$ 1 = \pm(-1) = \pm 1 $$
which is true. $1$ *does* in fact equal $1$ **or** $-1$ (in this case we obviously know it's $+1$, but that doesn't mean that the plus-or-minus expression is wrong, just kind of silly).

So the short answer is, you cannot undo the squares without introducing (manually) the plus-or-minus into the expression. After you do that, you may be able to determine *which* of them it is, but that's your own job.

As for your other question, why isn't it that $x^2 = 4 \implies \pm x = \pm 2$? Well, actually, I guess it *does*, but it's unnecessary to put the $\pm$ on *both* sides. You only need to put it on one. I remember myself once wondering why does $\pm$ get placed on only one side? Don't you need to do it to *both* sides? But this is a misunderstanding of what is going on when we make the logical leap from $x^2 = 4$ to $x = \pm 2$. You might think we are taking the $\pm \sqrt{\ \ } $ of both sides, but that is not really true. $\pm \sqrt{\ \ }$ is not a *function*, so the usual rule of applying it to both sides doesn't really make sense. Really all we're doing is just remembering that there is always two solutions to a quadratic, and thus we use that principle (and no other) when we deduce that $x^2 = 4 \implies x = \pm 2$.

Comment: Thank you! I was not hoping for this clear answer.

Comment: I do notice, however, that you are using an **implication** sign between x²=4 and x=+-2.  Why not use an **equivalent** sign?   Aren't those equations equivalent?

Comment: @StephenSafee: Yes, you could use an equivalency sign. Although the backwards implication wasn't relevant to the discussion, so no reason to emphasize it. But it does hold.

Answer (score 3):

Claiming $(-1)^2 = (1)^2$ implies $-1 = 1$ is more than just bad arithmetic, it is bad logic.

For instance,

I am not seven feet tall. Angela Merkel is not seven feet tall. Therefore I am Angela Merkel. This is false (but you'll have to take my word on it).

Answer (score 0):

$$x=2 \implies x^2=4 ~ ; ~  x=-2 \implies x^2=4$$

But ,

$$x^2=4  \not \implies x=2 ~~; x^2=4  \not \implies x=-2 $$

And also ;

$$x^2=4 \iff |x|=2 \implies x=\pm2~~ \text{(Both are possible)}$$

Comment: If I'm not mistaking you're using \not\implies try instead \not\rightarrow syou should get  $\not\rightarrow$, seems kinda better as the \not now doesn't even cross the arrow

Comment: Ah! This was helpful, Jaideep.  I was not aware about the absolute value nuance on the last line.